# Python run script after closing vm without nohup file

Tags: python, virtual-machine, nohup

I am trying to run my python script forever after closing my VM

I am using:

```
nohup python3 myscript.py &
```

My problem is, I have the output file `nohup` created which after 2 days is using all my VM's memory.
Is there a way to run my script forever without the `nohup` file and my memory problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
nohup python3 myscript.py > /dev/null &
```